# Extract particular value from column and exit from loop

Tags: bash, shell

I want to extract column dispstatus from below command and if all the entries are GREEN then i should come out of the loop.

```
sapcontrol -nr 01 -function GetProcessList

17.02.2020 01:40:34
GetProcessList
OK
name, description, dispstatus, textstatus, starttime, elapsedtime, pid
disp+work, Dispatcher, GREEN, Running, 2020 02 16 03:50:28, 21:50:06, 59404
igswd_mt, IGS Watchdog, GREEN, Running, 2020 02 16 03:50:28, 21:50:06, 59405
gwrd, Gateway, GREEN, Running, 2020 02 16 03:50:30, 21:50:04, 59423
icman, ICM, GREEN, Running, 2020 02 16 03:50:30, 21:50:04, 59424
```

For now i have used below command where instead of getting all the values i'm checking the counts of GREEN and exiting which is currently not what i intend to do. Can you please help me?

```
while true ; do status=`sapcontrol -nr 01 -function GetProcessList |awk -F ',' '{if ($3) print $3;}'|grep -i GREEN | wc -l`; sleep 2; if [[ $status -ge 2 ]]; then break ;fi; done
```

EDIT: some command in different lines.

```
while true ; do
   status=`sapcontrol -nr 01 -function GetProcessList |
      awk -F ',' '{if ($3) print $3;}'|
      grep -i GREEN |
      wc -l`
   sleep 2
   if [[ $status -ge 2 ]]; then
      break
   fi
done
```

Thanks,
Anup

Comment: How do we know how many there should be? Or do you mean exit with an error as soon hs `$3` is not "green"? See also [useless `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Use `if [ $status -ge 2 ];` or `if (( $status >= 2 ));`.

Comment: You don't want to count `GREEN`, but when do you want to break? On `YELLOW` and `RED`  ? Or when any record after the header line doesn't has `GREEN`? Is the header line always part of the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while true ; do
    status=$(sapcontrol -nr 01 -function GetProcessList)
    case $status in
        *GREEN*GREEN*GREEN*GREEN*) break;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: IMHO, there could be an issue 1- If there are more number of `GREEN` string are present, 2- if string is present other than specific column(I believe OP mentioned clearly that on a specific column OP needs to check this), that's why I went to check column number for the string in first line. These are just my thoughts rest OP only could let us know on this one.